# Is there a way I can Export and stack Salesforce data to a google sheet?

Tags: google-sheets, salesforce

I am trying to create a google sheet that updates and stacks the data from a Salesforce report on a daily basis. I tried to use the Data connector for Salesforce add, it exports the data just fine but when I change the date, it replaces everything it exported the first time. What I wanted it to do is to Extract the data today, store it in the sheet, and Export another time tomorrow adding the data to the existing one. I have no coding knowledge and SQL stuff and I'm trying to learn things to help my work.

Your response is highly appreciated